# Is branch-prediction a big issue in PHP?

Tags: php, branch-prediction

Is [branch prediction](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) a big issue in PHP too?

> I am referring to this answer: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1069083)

So in C++ and Java a sorted array is computed faster than an unsorted, because the processor can predict the next steps correctly.

Would this refer to PHP programs the same way?

Comment: Unlikely: in PHP, an array is a hashmap, no prediction involved

Comment: So there is no way of getting a benefit by this? Maybe you could use different arrays, than the standard php arrays (which are hashmaps indeed) to achieve an advantage?

Comment: Double linked hashmap.

Comment: @MarkBaker, the reason why the sorted array behaved better had nothing to do with its memory layout. Accessing a sorted hash map may also work better in terms of branch prediction, if it means that your CPU keeps going through the same control flow path.

Comment: this question has an anwer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294457/branch-prediction-at-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Branch prediction at php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294457/branch-prediction-at-php)