# Generate an array from a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this:

```
$str = '35-3|24-6|72-1|16-5';
```

I want to generate an array:

```
$arr = array (

    35 => 3,
    24 => 6,
    72 => 1,
    16 => 5

);
```

What's the best and simplest way?

Comment: Your `$arr` is not multidimensional.

Comment: Read about explode function in php

Comment: @Oras the explode function  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can only split by one delimiter. This would not yield an associative array like the OP wants.

Comment: @jdwire He can use it twice inside a loop generated based on the first use of explode.

Comment: @Oras Right, he can use it like GBD is suggesting.

Comment: ok now for both GBD and air4x answers they are functional, but for an intense traffic app, which is better and less resource consuming?

Comment: @medk just test it online or do some intensief loops while registering the time consumed to execute the script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235369/measuring-the-elapsed-time-between-code-segments-in-php/11235396

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try as below

```
$str = '35-3|24-6|72-1|16-5';

$data = explode("|",$str);
$arr = array();
foreach($data as $value){
  $part = explode('-',$value);
  $arr[$part[0]]=$part[1];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: hi, can you explian in depth?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)\-(\d*)/', $str, $matches)) {
  $arr = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}
```